# Jquery hide open divs before open a new one

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a list of product where the product information is hidden and ill use jquery to slide down the information on click . the problem is that i want the prev. information to slide up when the user is clicking another product .

Im getting it to close the previous one but it dont open the next .

Here are the link the user will click for more information.

```
    <div class="list-op" target="<?php echo $i ?>" style="display:inline;"></div>
```

Here are the hiden divs

```
    <div id="div<?php echo $i ?>" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
                <div class="list-image">
                    <a  href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-image" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                        <img class="tTip" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(140, 183); ?>" width="140" height="183" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>
```

here is my jquery code for the event

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
$('.list-op').click(function () {
    var itemid = '#div' + $(this).attr('target'); //id of the element to show/hide.

    //Show the element if nothing is shown.
    if ($('.aktiv').length === 0) {
        $(itemid).slideToggle("slow");
        $(itemid).addClass('aktiv');

        //Hide the element if it is shown.
    } else if (itemid == "#" + $('.aktiv').attr('id')) {
        $('.aktiv').slideToggle("slow");
        $(itemid).removeClass('aktiv');

        //Otherwise, switch out the current element for the next one sequentially.
    } else {
        $('.aktiv').slideToggle(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('aktiv');
            if ($(".targetDiv:animated").length === 0) {
                $(itemid).slideToggle("slow");
                $(itemid).addClass('aktiv');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: You miss the closing `>` at `<div class="list-image"` and a space `<div id="div<?php echo $i ?>"` < here

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for that ill correct it but it still dosent work

Comment: Have you checked if `if ($('.aktiv').length === 0)` returns true?

Comment: No i havent how can i check this

Comment: just put a `console.log` or `alert()` there...

Comment: im sorry for my lack of experience in the jquery field im not getting alert() to work the hole function stopps to function can you help me by showing

Comment: See you got it sorted! Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your jquery to this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.list-op').click(function () {
        var itemid = '#div' + $(this).attr('target'); //id of the element to show/hide.

        // this is already shown
        var stop = $(itemid).hasClass('aktiv')

        $('.aktiv').slideToggle("slow").removeClass('aktiv');

        if(stop) return;

        $(itemid).slideToggle("slow").addClass('aktiv');        
    })
});
```